# Working with Constrained generic functions confuses me

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
function getMinimum<T extends {length : number}>(arg1 : T, arg2 : T) : T {
    if (arg1.length >= arg2.length) {
        return arg2;
    }

    else {
        return arg1;
    }
}

let str = "Hello world"; 
const res0 = getMinimum([1, 2, 3], str); // Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
const res1 = getMinimum([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}); // res1 type - number[] | {length: number}
```

In the above code block, getMinimum([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}) works fine but getMinimum([1, 2, 3], str) triggers a type error.

I think, it shouldn't trigger a type error and res0 should be assigned a type of: number[] | string. But Typescript doesn't do that for res0 but it does that for res1, why is there a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript use generics not only to constrain the type of the parameters but also to infer the type of the supplied arguments.

A simple way to visualise it is to wonder what it would look like if the user supplied the value of the generic manually: `getMinimum<number[]>([1, 2, 3], str)`. Here it is more obvious that `number[]` fits `[1, 2, 3]` but not `"Hello world"`.

So you need a distinct generic for each parameter when their type needs to be different, even though they satisfy the same constraint:

```js
type Length = { length : number };

function getMinimum<T extends Length, U extends Length>(arg1 : T, arg2 : U) : T | U {
    if (arg1.length >= arg2.length) {
        return arg2;
    }

    else {
        return arg1;
    }
}
```

As for why `getMinimum([1, 2, 3], { length: 12 })` passes with your implementation while `getMinimum([1, 2, 3], str)` doesn't:

> A little disclaimer: I am not "in the know", what follows is a mental model.

When you map 2 arguments to a single generic, TS *probably* does the following:

- infer the types of each argument independently;
- check if these types are compatible with the constraint;
- if they are not, reject the arguments;
- if they are, intersect them to find a common type
- if the intersection produces `never`, reject the first argument and mention the second in the error.

In the case of `getMinimum([1, 2, 3], { length: 12 })`: TS infers `number[]` for `arg1` and `{length: number}` for `arg2`, checks that they are assignable to `{ length: number }`, then intersect them, end up with `number[]` and accepts the type.

In the case of `getMinimum([1, 2, 3], str)`: TS infers `number[]` for `arg1` and `string` for `arg2`, checks that they are assignable to `{ length: number }`, then intersect them, end up with `never` and rejects the first one.

There is a common type that would satisfy `{ length: number }` and work for both `number[]` and `string`: that's `{ length: number } & (string | number[])`, but TS does not try to infer that type. A possible reason for this is that if it did, it would widen the type of the generic so that it works for the 2 arguments, but what we are generally after is inferring the most narrow type possible, because narrow types are more useful.

A distinction should also be made between type inference and type checking: TS can totally (and more often than not) infer the correct return type even when the type checker rejects the arguments, because they are 2 different algorithms. Here it is clear that `T` in return type position should be `typeof arg1 | typeof arg2`

Comment: Why does getMinimum([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}) work then? If I supply a generic type to the last function call in my example, the function call looks like this: getMinimum<number[]>([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}). So in this case, {length: 12} is not of type: number[], but it still works. Typescript infers the result to be of type: number[] | {length: number}.

Comment: That's weird, it should not work https://tsplay.dev/w1EG8w I will edit my answer to address your question. It does feel incomplete as it is.

Comment: Just to be clear, getMinimum([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}) assigns type number[] | {length number} to the returned value but getMinimum<number[]>([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}) raises a type error which is good. But getMinimum([1, 2, 3], {length: 12}) shouldn't be possible based on your previous explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by implicitly inferred types of the arguments. To make your function accept both and array string you can use `union` type:

```
function getMinimum<T extends { length: number }>(arg1: T, arg2: T | string): T {
  if (arg1.length >= (arg2 as T).length) {
    return arg2 as T;
  } else {
    return arg1;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use explicit generic in the `res0`:

```
const res0 = getMinimum<number[] | string>([1, 2, 3], str);
```

Comment: With this implementation, `res0` will return the type of `arg1` when the type is inferred. It's really not a good option. Don't do this.